# How to get Mapper Progress from a running mapreduce job

Tags: java, mapreduce, hadoop2

Can anyone help me with the below question.

How to get the mapper **splits** **progress** from a **dead** mapreduce job.

I mean by the time the job is dead, it might had completed some mapper tasks. i need the succeeded map tasks progress in terms of percentage.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Look at example 2 [here](http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobStatus).

Replace the `if (!job.isJobComplete()) {` with `if (job.isJobComplete()) {` and then use the `mapProgress()` function to determine the map status for completed jobs.

I know maybe it's not what you're looking for such as command line codes or web console features, but this can be a last resort.

PS: The docs talk about using JobProfile instead. Look at that too.